# Detection of people presence in a room based on data from sensors

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, classification, iot

I have a binary classification problem:

There some sensors in a room (humidity, temperature, sound/noise, infrared etc.) that collect data every N minutes. When people come into/leave the room, sensors react on this action. So, after some time, dataset will look like that:

```
<sensor_1> <sensor_2> ... <sensor_i> <time> | <people in room?>
   ...         ...           ...       ...         yes/no
```

In this way, how should I address this problem? Should I take into consideration previous readings from sensors and due to this use time-series techniques or LSTM? Can I simply apply SVM or neural net for this task?

Comment: I do not think that the task you are looking at is time dependent. You should start with a simple tool, like logistic regression, SVM or Random Forests. Usually, starting with a quick and dirty model and iterating beats worrying overmuch about algorithms ahead of the time. If you need a more complicated model, you will discover that, if you iterate.

Comment: While it's possible, that the infrared data is good enough to predict this by itself (without a time-series approach), an approach involving time should be much better in regards to the parameters *humidity* and *temperature*(my intuition). I would start with a simple window-based approach (to recognize deltas in *humidity* and *temperature*). It might be a good idea to convert these two features to a delta-value. On top of this a simple SVM should be enough. Of course one has to decide on the window-size. Besides that, the general approach by @JohnYetter sounds good. Start simple and iterate

Comment: I agree with John and Sascha that an SVM should do the job.  This is my favorite classifier for this type of problem.  I don't believe you need to consider time.  You haven't stated whether or not you will be labeling your training data.  That is a critical step.

Comment: @BrianO'Donnell Yes, data will be labeled.